# .htaccess rewriterule and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress page I'm trying to redirect to from the root directory. I can't use the traditional built in method of setting a wordpress page as the home page because of technical reasons caused by a plugin I'm using. So I'm trying to outsmart the plugin by using htaccess.
Here is what I currently am trying in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /?grp_pages=4 [NC]
```

It's throwing an Internal Server Error. I think this is hiding wordpress' index.php file from itself and causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the query string isn't already set:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^grp_pages=
RewriteRule ^$ /?grp_pages=4 [NC]
```